# How do we call Base class Constructor from Derived Class using delegating Constructors

Tags: c++, oop, constructor-overloading, inherited-constructors

I know and I have read many threads to call a base class constructor from a Derived class, But I wanted to implement it using Delegating constructors

Here is my code

The error states

"A delegating constructor cannot have other mem-initializers"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Shivang101
class Base
{
private:
    int value;

public:
    Base() : value{0}
    {
        cout << "Base no args constructor called" << endl;
    }
    Base(int x) : value{x}
    {
        cout << "Base (int) overloaded constructor called" << endl;
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "Base Destructor called" << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{

private:
    int testing_value;
    int doubled_value;
    // using Base ::Base;

public:
    Derived() : Derived{0, 0}
    {
        cout << "NO arg constructor called" << endl;
    };
    // In the below line I'm Trying a call the base class constructor but getting error
    Derived(int testing_val) : Base{testing_val}, Derived{testing_val, 0}
    {
        cout << "One arg constructor called" << endl;
    }
    
    Derived(int testing_val, int doubled_val) : testing_value{testing_val}, doubled_value{doubled_val}
    {
        cout << "Delegating constructor/ overloaded called" << endl;
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
        cout << "Derived destructor called" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived d{1000};
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to call my base class constructor and initialize the "value" in **Base** class as "1000" and initialize the "testing_*value" and "doubled_*value" in the **Derived** class as "1000" and "2000" respectively

Comment: please do not paraphrase the error but include the complete error message in the question

Comment: "If the name of the class itself appears as class-or-identifier in the member initializer list, then the list must consist of that one member initializer only" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Youcannot call both a delegating constructor and a base constructor at the same time.The base constructor is already being called by the constructor you delegated to.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is responsible for initializing all members and base subobjects.

A delegating constructor delegates to a different constructor.

It cannot be both. Either you delegate elsewhere or you initialize members and base subobjects.

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

> Delegating constructor
>
> If the name of the class itself appears as class-or-identifier in the
> member initializer list, then the list must consist of that one member
> initializer only; such a constructor is known as the delegating
> constructor, and the constructor selected by the only member of the
> initializer list is the target constructor

I suppose you can rearrange the constructors to achieve desired effect. Though I don't see how it can be done without implementing one more constructor or change the way of delegating, because currently the one taking two arguments calls the default constructor of `Base`, but the one delegating to it attempts to call `Base{testing_val}`.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution to my Question

We can call the Base Class Constructor from Derived Class using Delegating constructor by calling the Base class constructor in the delegating constructor itself

In the I was passing Base Class constructor call from overload to delegating constructor
No I have called Base Class Constructor from the Delegating constructor itself

````
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Shivang101
class Base
{
private:
public:
    int value;
    int value2;
    Base() : value{0}
    {
        cout << "Base no args constructor called" << endl;
    }
    Base(int x) : value{x}
    {
        cout << "Base (int) overloaded constructor called" << endl;
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "Base Destructor called" << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{

private:
public:
    int testing_value;
    int doubled_value;
    // using Base ::Base;

    Derived() : Derived{0, 0}
    {
        cout << "NO arg constructor called" << endl;
    };

    Derived(int testing_val) : Derived{testing_val, 0}
    {
        cout << "One arg constructor called" << endl;
    }

    Derived(int testing_val, int doubled_val) : Base{testing_val}, testing_value{testing_val}, doubled_value{doubled_val * 2}
    {
        cout << "Delegating constructor/ overloaded called" << endl;
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
        cout << "Derived destructor called" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived d{1000};
    cout << d.value << endl;

    return 0;
}
    ```
````